# DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'-- in Local storage

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to put a div with some text in the header area before row Starts...

And creating element and adding textnode and appending code :

```
let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.className = 'Hello';
newDiv.id = 'HelloId';
newDiv.setAttribute('title', 'This Is Test');
let chNode = document.createTextNode('Something is Here');
newDiv.appendChild(chNode)
newDiv.style.background = 'red';
newDiv.style.padding = '2%';
let headContainer = document.querySelector('header .container');
let headh1 = document.querySelector('header h1');
headContainer.insertBefore(newDiv, headh1)
console.log(headh1)
```

In HTML it looks Like

```
  <header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 id="header-title">Item Lister</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" placeholder="Search Items...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

But I am getting an error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If so, isn't jQuery available to you?

Comment: Yes i M using Jquery And Bootstrap JS Also:

<script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: What about `$('header').append('whatever')`?

Comment: The `h1` header you select, is a (direct) child of `<div class="col-md-6">`, not a (direct) child of `<header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">`, so you're using the wrong parent node to use insertBefore() on, hence the error.

Comment: @Shilly Dude Thank You It was Worked It was Not That Parent, I get it Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You mean this? Insert the div before the header?

```js
let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.className = 'Hello';
newDiv.id = 'Hello Id';
newDiv.setAttribute('tile', 'This Is Test');
let chNode = document.createTextNode('Something is Here');
newDiv.appendChild(chNode)
newDiv.style.background = 'red';
newDiv.style.padding = '2%';

let container = document.querySelector('header > .container')
let headh1 = container.querySelector('h1');
console.log(headh1)

headh1.closest("div").insertBefore(newDiv, headh1)
```

```html
<header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 id="header-title">Item Lister</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" placeholder="Search Items...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Or before the row?

```js
let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.className = 'Hello';
newDiv.id = 'Hello Id';
newDiv.setAttribute('tile', 'This Is Test');
let chNode = document.createTextNode('Something is Here');
newDiv.appendChild(chNode)
newDiv.style.background = 'red';
newDiv.style.padding = '2%';

let container = document.querySelector('header > .container')
let headh1 = container.querySelector('h1');
let row = headh1.closest(".row")
container.insertBefore(newDiv, row)
```

```html
<header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 id="header-title">Item Lister</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" placeholder="Search Items...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```